# Dialogflow Rule-based grammar matching

Tags: android-intent, dialogflow-es, chatbot, dependency-parsing

I am doing some research about chatbots and more specifically Dialogflow.
When I was searching for the intent classification I find out that Dialogflow is using rule-based grammar matching and ML matching.
I tried to find more information about the rule-based grammar matching but I couldn't find anything...
Is this the same as dependency parsing?
Can someone help me with some useful sources where I can get more information about how this alogritme is working?

Thanks in advance!